# How do I change a message based on the time of the day?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, time

I want to change content based on the time of the day, which tells if my business is open or closed. I use the following Javascript:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dt = new Date();
    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
    enter code here

    if (day <= 0) {
        if (time < "11:00:00") {
            document.write('Good morning! We are currently closed, you can reach us at 11 AM')
        } else if (time > "16:30:00" && time < "18:00:00") {
            document.write('Good afternoon! We are currently closed. You can reach us tomorrow')
        } else if (time > "18:00:00") {
            document.write('Good evening! We are currently closed. You can reach us tomorrow')
        } else {
            document.write('Customer service: &nbsp;&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> &nbsp;+1 555.234.987')
        }
    } else if (day <= 1) {
        if (time < "09:00:00") {
            document.write('Good morning! We are currently closed, you can reach us at 9 AM')
        } else if (time > "19:00:00") {
            document.write('Good evening! We are currently closed, you can reach us tomorrow')
        } else {
            document.write('Customer Service: &nbsp;&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> &nbsp;+1 555.234.987')
        }
    } 
</script>
```

And so on from Monday to Sunday.

For some reason the text is displaying another text, so when it is 10AM on Monday, the text shows "Good evening! We are currently closed, you can reach us tomorrow"

I know I did something wrong, but I can't figure out what...

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare strings like this.

Use:

```
$hour = dt.getHours();
```

and then:

```
if ($hour > 10) {
 ..
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you try to make if on String not Numers...

Try to use if with only dt.getHours():

```
if (dt.getHours() < 11) {
document.write('Good morning! We are currently closed, you can reach us at 11 AM')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following elements:

First get the day, hours and minutes

```
var dt = new Date();
var day = dt.getDay();
var hour = dt.getHours();
var minute= dt.getMinutes();
```

Make a switch for the days:

```
switch(day) {
    case 0:
        //Be carefull! This is Sunday!
        break;
    case 1:
        //Monday
        break;
    case 2:
        //Thuesday
        break;
}
```

And in the cases compare the times:

```
    case 1:
    if (hour < 11) {
        document.write('Good morning! We are currently closed, you can reach us at 11 AM')
    } else if (((hour >= 16 && minutes >= 30) || hour >= 17) && hour < 18) {
        document.write('Good afternoon! We are currently closed. You can reach us tomorrow')
    } else if (hour >= 18) {
        document.write('Good evening! We are currently closed. You can reach us tomorrow')
    } else {
        document.write('Customer service: &nbsp;&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> &nbsp;+1 555.234.987')
    }
        break;
```

Rest should be easy copy paste :)

Comment: I tried this, but the console says that there is an unexpected token case

Comment: Cant help if i dont see the code you created. Maybe you can make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your new code or edit it in your question.